# Extjs custom grid row grouping

Tags: extjs, grid

I met some problems with creating table using Extjs. My table has difficult structure

```
-------------------------------------------|
|              |                 |    4    |  
|              |       2          ---------|
|              |                 |    5    |
|    1         |---------------------------|
|              |                 |    6    |  
|              |       3          ---------|
|              |                 |    7    |
-------------------------------------------|
```

The data from the server are as following:

```
1 2 4 
1 2 5
1 3 6
1 3 7
```

Every sequence is an array
I need them to be grouped as at the picture above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to group on the first two columns but unfortunately Ext.data.Store only supports one level of grouping.  You'll have to extend Store to support more and Ext.grid.feature.Grouping to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PivotGrid`. Example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/pivotgrid/simple.html

Unfortunately it is only available in Ext JS 3. It should be available in Ext JS 4.1 though.